# SQL join result errors

Tags: sql, left-join, db2-400

I'm trying to run this join and I'm not receiving the correct values.

My first query return like 25,000 record

```
SELECT count(*) from table1 as DSO,
table2 as EAR
WHERE
(UCASE(TRIM(EAR.value)) = UCASE(TRIM(DSO.value))
 AND 
UCASE(TRIM(EAR.value1) = UCASE(TRIM(DSO.value1))
```

my second Query return like 3,000,000

```
SELECT count(*) from table1 as DSO
left join table2 as EAR,
ON
(UCASE(TRIM(EAR.value)) = UCASE(TRIM(DSO.value))
 AND 
UCASE(TRIM(EAR.value1) = UCASE(TRIM(DSO.value1))
```

The total of records of the table 1 are like 45,000, thats what I Should recieve.

Comment: You probably have multiple matches in table2 for some or all of your records in table1. It will return a record for each one of those cases, as well as a record for each case where there is no match.

Comment: WHERE EAR.value IS NOT NULL

Comment: Multiple from's joined with a `WHERE`-clause are the same as an `INNER JOIN`, often shortened as `JOIN`. `LEFT JOIN` will have a different result since it also shows all records from `DSO` without a match in `EAR`.

Comment: Actually thats what I want all the records from DSO even that they do not have a match in EAR but the DSO have like 45,000 record and the count return like 3,000,000

Comment: Please confirm... Your JOIN version query... if it has the comma or not after EAR ( as EAR, ) or not... If so, that surprises me that it would run.  You should NOT have the comma.  It implies.. hey, there is another table coming and that is called "ON" as apposed to the "ON" being the join condition.

Comment: Not it do not have the comma, i type it by mistake when I post the question.

Answer (score 0):

First query is an INNER JOIN and second one is a LEFT JOIN. You should expect quite different results. Also, look at the way db2400 treats NULLs with the UCASE and TRIM functions. My guess is that your left join is making some matches that you don't want.

The INNER JOIN in the first query is going to exclude any records from table1 that don't have a match in table2. That pretty quickly explains the lower count.

Either join will happily create more than one row for each record in table1 if it finds multiple matches in table2. The difference is that the LEFT JOIN will ALSO create one row for each record in table1 that doesn't have a match in table2. It sounds like you expect there to be a 1:1 match between the two tables, but that is not what you are getting.